# Run a script on Raspian startup but not on terminal open

Tags: bash, terminal, raspbian

I have added a command in `.bashrc` to run a script at startup of my Raspberry Pi, but everytime I open a new terminal the same script executes again.

Is there any way I can make this script run only on startup / power up and not each time I open a new terminal?

Comment: You'll need to run your script via System V init style run-level scripts or systemd scripts .. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html .. another way can be to introduce a flag that ensures your script runs only once on boot

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is being executed every time a `bash` is started, which involves opening a new terminal. Add your script invocation to `/etc/rc.local`.